# Let $u(z)$ be a harmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|u(z)| \leq \sqrt{|z|}$. Show $u$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u(z)$ be a harmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $|u(z)| \leq \sqrt{|z|}$. Show $u$ is constant.

We can say $u(z) = \text{Re}f(z)$ for some entire $f$. Liouville would give $f$ is constant, and thus $u$ is constant. However, I have had a hard time obtaining a bound for $f$, or for related function.

Another route I have thought through is to use Picard's Little theorem, but again I have trouble finding points $f$ will not take.

Any tips appreciated, thank you.

Comment: By translation we may assume $f(0)=0$, which means $f(z)$ has a zero at $0$. Thus it makes sense to define a entire function $g(z)$ satisfying $f(z)=zg(z)$. Now what bound can be obtained on $g(z)$?

Comment: @CaveJohnson I worked with this hint for a while, but I run into the same problems as before. However, I could follow a similar argument as below, but with $g$. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention the  Borel-Caratheodory theorem. This is actually what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make use of some standard inequalities related to Maximum Modulus Principle. [It is perhaps possible to simplify this proof]. Let $f$ be continuous on $\{z:\left\vert z\right\vert \leq R\}$ and
holomorphic on $B(0,R).$ Let $M(r)=\sup \{\left\vert f(z)\right\vert
:\left\vert z\right\vert =r\}$ and $\phi (r)=\sup \{\Re f(z):\left\vert
z\right\vert =r\}$ for $0\leq r\leq R$. Then $$M(r)\leq \frac{R-r}{R+r}%
\Re f(0)+\frac{2r}{R+r}\phi (r)$$ and $$M(r)\leq \frac{R-r}{R+r}%
\left\vert f(0)\right\vert +\frac{2r}{R+r}\phi (r)$$ for $0\leq r\leq R.$

Corollary: if $f$ is an entire function such that $\Re f(z)\leq B\left\vert
z\right\vert ^{n}$ for $\left\vert z\right\vert \geq R$ then $f$ is a
polynomial of degree at most $n.$

We have $\phi (r)\leq Br^{n}$ for $r\geq R$. Hence $M(r)\leq \frac{2r-r}{2r+r}\left\vert
f(0)\right\vert +\frac{2r}{2r+r}\phi (r)\leq \frac{1}{3}\left\vert
f(0)\right\vert +\frac{2}{3}Br^{n}$ and $\left\vert f(z)\right\vert \leq 
\frac{1}{3}\left\vert f(0)\right\vert +\frac{2}{3}B\left\vert z\right\vert
^{n}$ if $\left\vert z\right\vert \geq R.$ This implies that $f$ is a
polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Now to answer the present question let $f$ be an entire function with real part $u$. Consider $f^{2}$. This is  an entire function and its real part does not exceed $u^{2}(z)\leq |z|$. Hence $f^{2}$ is polynomial of degree at most $1$. From this it trivial to complete the proof.

Comment: The book by Burckel (Classical Complex Analysis) has a proof of the inequalities I have used.

Comment: Thank you. For reference; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Carath%C3%A9odory_theorem